# curl with output in file and the output file name has a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, curl

I want to create a folder if it's not exist. 
After that i want to get a file from a url with login and password.

But by my example curl don't used the variable in the output.

How can i create the variable for using it in the output ? What is the right syntax ?

```html
SET TS=%TIME: =0%
SET DS=%DATE: =0%
SET path=%CD%
SET logfile=%path%\%DS:~6,4%_%DS:~3,2%_%DS:~0,2%\%TS:~0,2%%TS:~3,2%%TS:~6,2%_example.gz

if not exist %path%\%DS:~6,4%_%DS:~3,2%_%DS:~0,2% mkdir %DS:~6,4%_%DS:~3,2%_%DS:~0,2%

curl -u loginname:pw http://example.url.com/example.gz > @%logfile%
```

Comment: Do not set a variable to the name `%path%`, unless you really know what you are doing. In this case you don't even need to set it, you can use `%CD%` directly, if you really want the current directory as opposed to the directory holding the script itself. If you're intending to run for anyone not running under your current user profile, your `%date%` and `%time%` variables cannot be guaranteed to provide the same output. If that's the case, you'll need to use a non user/locale dependent method. Finally, please use doublequotes, and remove the prepending `@` character from your output filename.

Comment: Hey, @Tibor, Every posts should be in English

Comment: Have you mixed up`%cd%` with `%path%`?

Comment: "%logfile%" works

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using the advice I provided in my comment:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "logfile="
For /F "Tokens=1-6Delims=/: " %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%RoboCopy.exe" /NJH /L "\|" Null^"'
)Do If Not Defined logfile Set "logfile=%~dp0%%A_%%B_%%C\%%D%%E%%F_example.gz"
If Not Exist "%logfile%\" MD "%logfile%"
"P:\athTo\CURL.exe" -u loginname:pw http://example.url.com/example.gz>"%logfile%"
```

If `CURL.exe` is located in the same location as the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), you can change `P:\athTo\` to `%~dp0`, if it's in the current directory, replace it with `%__CD__%` or `%CD%\`